# Minimal Distance between two curves

Tags: calculus

What is the minimal distance between curves?

1. $y = |x| + 1$
2. $y = \arctan(2x)$

I need to set a point with $\cos(t), \sin(t)$?

Comment: The graph of $y=\arctan2x$ is generally called a *curve*, not a line. The graph of $y=|x|+1$ isn't a line, either.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(a,|a|+1)$ be a point on the first curve and let $(b,\arctan(2b))$ be a point on the second curve.
Half the distance between the two points squared is $$\frac{1}{2}d^2 = \frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2+\frac{1}{2}(|a|+1-\arctan(2b))^2.$$

To find the minimum of this expression we set the partial derivatives to zero:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial d^2}{\partial a} = (a-b)+(|a|+1-\arctan(2b))\frac{a}{|a|} = 0$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial d^2}{\partial b} = (b-a)+(|a|+1-\arctan(2b))\frac{-2}{1+4b^2}=0.$$

Adding these two equations gives
$$ (|a|+1-\arctan(2b))\left(\frac{a}{|a|}-\frac{2}{1+4b^2}\right)=0.$$

If the first term is to be zero, then $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial d^2}{a}=0$ implies $a=b$, there is no solution for $1+|a|=\arctan(2a)$ however.
If the second term is to be zero, we have $a>0$ and $b=\pm\frac{1}{2}$.
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial d^2}{a}=0$ then reduces to $$ 0=a\mp\frac{1}{2}+(a+1-\arctan(\pm 1)) = 2a+1\mp\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$

Since $a>0$ we need to pick $b=\frac{1}{2}$ and thus $a = \frac{\pi-2}{8}$.

Hence the closest points are $(\frac{\pi-2}{8},\frac{\pi+6}{8})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\pi}{4})$ and their distance is $$\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi-2}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\pi+6}{8}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}(6-\pi)}{8}.$$

Comment: d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2) this is the equation for distance between point, why you did half squared distance between the point?

Comment: Because minimizing half the square distance is the same as minimizing the distance and it makes the calculations a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

One shortcut here is to note that curves 1, 2 (say $f(x)$, $g(x)$) have a co-normal line passing between the closest two points.

Therefore, since $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x>0$ then just find where $g'(x) = 1$ or

\begin{align}&\frac{2}{4x^2 +1} = 1\\
&2 = 4x^2 + 1\\
&\bf{x = \pm 1/2}\end{align}